# Three.js: I cant change far and near plan of camera. Why?

Tags: three.js, camera

I have some object at 0,0,0. Object size changes arbitrary. So I ajust camera z-position to see whole object. I calculate proper camera.position.z, camera.near = camera.position.z/2, camera.far = camera.position.z*2.

In debbuger I see correct camera properties (as I set dynamically) but renderer does not take into account new far and near plan depth (z-postion works ok). Far and near properties equal initial values (set in new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...) operator).

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to call

```
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

if you change the `fov`, `aspect`, `near`, or `far` properties.

three.js r.92